# Как получить автоинкрементный id после insert?

Tags: php, mysql

Как получить id после добавления строки  в БД?

Comment: Вы же уже об этом спрашивали. Мне показалось вам все разъяснили.

В MySQL нет строк. Возможно вы имеете ввиду "как получить id последней записи в MySql?" ?

Comment: Можно и это

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

[mysqli::$insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php)

[PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Пользуйтесь на здоровье. Единственное, что я бы посоветовал это не использовать первую функцию потому что устарела.

Comment: Хочу добавить, что это разные расширения, дабы не путаться, и первое уже устарело, третье самое актуальное.